# What database design do you favor; one with actual physical relations or one that mimics it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-design, relational-database

What is the best practice while designing a relational database? To have physical relationships between tables (actual line drawn from table to table(s)) or mimic the relationship only?

E.g.

**TableA** has columns

```
ID, Name
```

**TableB** has columns

```
ID, CNIC, TableA_ID
```

Now, **TableA_ID** doesn't have an actual foreign key constraint on it but stills stores the value that maps to the **ID** column of TableA.

I consider the later to be good and I believe that the former slows down and has cascade operation problems?

Comment: If you have a foreign key constraint, you should declare it.

Comment: Right, but what are the shortcomings if I do so or do it the other way like mimic it?

Comment: You can't apply key constraints using later approach and it's not recommended.

Comment: It depends on what database you are creating.
If you are going to create OLTP-system, then you should use FK, because you need data integrity.

If you are going to create data warehouse, then FK is not always needed.

Comment: The "latter" is a terrible idea. You are using a **relational** database and foreign keys are the implementation of relations. Go read about the history of databases - you have much to learn about what problems drove the concept and implementation. Short answer - your "data" becomes corrupted garbage.

Answer (score 5):

One of the main jobs of a database is to ensure [data integrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_integrity).
A part of data integrity is [referential integrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity).
Relational databases ensure referential integrity with Foreign key constraints.

Remove the constraint, and you remove the database ability to guard against corrupt data.

Therefor, you should always specify foreign keys when your tables are related, even at the price of a performance penalty (which is usually negligible anyway).

You can't mimic a constraint if it doesn't exist - even if you have a front-end application that validates all the data being entered into the database - nothing is stopping a developer, DBA, or anyone that has a direct access to the database to enter corrupt data by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Relational model doesn't contains any kind of physical links. One relation (table) may have a reference to other one using pairs "key--foreign key" ("key" may not be a primary). To ensure the integrity of references the foreign key constraint is required. Foreign key constraint should be used in your design "by default".

Usually, a database designer can add an index on FK columns and don't take into consideration any other performance issues because they are well managed in production (i.e. temporary disabling FK checks, bulk load operations ignore FK etc).

Comment: the link when you generate a diagram.. i meant that. visual link

Comment: the link between tables on a diagram means the reference. Normally, it should generate a FK in the script.